Why does my microphone only work when 'listen to this device' is checked?
The built in Realtek microphone on my Windows 10 laptop is not working.
If I go to Microphone Properties and go to the 'Listen' tab and check 'Listen to this Device' then I will hear the test input echoed back through the speakers.  This shows me that the hardware and some layer in the OS is able to pick up sound.   However, if that setting is disabled then the device tests shows no input.
In either case, programs like Audacity reports an error like " "Error opening recording device.\nError code: -9999 Unanticipated host error."   That happens if I set the host to MME, WASAPI or DirectSound.
I have upgraded and downgraded RealTek drivers and broken something along the way.  What do I do?

It seemed to be due to a privacy setting.   Windows Key -> Privacy -> Microphone -> Allow apps to access your microphone.
No idea why this applied in the Sound settings.

Why wouldn’t it? Anyway you should submit that as your answer.

Because the sound test was in the control panel itself - I wouldn't have counted that as an app.

The setting giving desktop applications permission to your microphone. The sound test has nothing to do with if an desktop application has that permission

The problem seemed to go away when I went into:

Windows Key -> Privacy -> Microphone -> Allow apps to access your microphone

